# How to create a UITextView programatically, inside UIView that is added programatically too?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

I am trying to make a text acceptor view like Instagram and Snapchat.

I am trying to add a UITextview (programatically) inside a UIView thats also added programatically. Below is the code I am trying to use to add the UITextView, but it is not working when added with UIView code. Please help.
[image: This is how it shows up when i add text view along with uiview]
What I am trying to achieve is:  [image: I am trying to achieve this text view inside the red uiview in previous image]
import UIKit

```
    class TextViewViewController: UIViewController {
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            let View1: UIView = {
                let viewView = UIView()
                viewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                viewView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                viewView.backgroundColor = .red
                viewView.clipsToBounds = true
                return viewView
            }()
    
            self.view.addSubview(View1)
    
            View1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            View1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            View1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 250).isActive = true
            View1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -250).isActive = true
            
            let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 250.0, height: 100.0))
            textView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
             
             textView.center = self.view.center
             textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
             textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
             
             // Use RGB colour
             textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 39/255, green: 53/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1)
             
             // Update UITextView font size and colour
             textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
             textView.textColor = UIColor.white
             textView.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 17)
  
             // Make UITextView web links clickable
             textView.isSelectable = true
             textView.isEditable = false
             textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link
             
             // Make UITextView corners rounded
             textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

             // Make UITextView Editable
             textView.isEditable = true
            View1.addSubview(textView)
//
//        let textView: UITextView = {
//            let tv = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 90.0, width: 100.0, height: 50.0))
//            tv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
//            tv.center = self.view.center
//            tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
//            tv.textColor = UIColor.blue
//            tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
//            return tv
//        }()
//
//        View1.addSubview(textView)
        
//        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
//        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
//        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
//        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: `but it is not working` is not good enough. Please be more specific.

Comment: When i add the text view code , it shows up the text view correctly. But when added along with the UIView, only the uiview shows up and not the textview thats added. @Paulw11 ,@Desdenova

Comment: I'm guessing you commented out text view's constraints because it didn't work either way? You need those constraints. Also you need `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the text view as well.

Comment: Tried the changes and it worked, thanks a lot! @Desdenova

Comment: 'View1'?  That's an interesting way of naming an IBOutlet object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the next line of code

```
textView.center = self.view.center
```

Get rid of it and you will see the textView in the view hierarchy

[image]